# Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>

Tags: bibliographies

I have a really weird problem with my thesis where I'm really stuck. All of a sudden it started throwing a very weird error message, which makes no sense to me and I couldn't find out what the problem is. So now I've got a file that won't compile anymore, no matter which parts I disable the error message just stays and refers to a line where the error can't actually be.

the error message it throws is:
! Missing \endcsname inserted.

\protect
l.46 \bibcite{B�ro08}{0}
The control sequence marked  should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

the thing is, I've got an entry named \bibitem{Biro08}. It was initially Bíro, so that was the first thing I changed, but it did nothing at all. Then I tried compiling it without the bibliography, nothing, still throwing the same error message. I actually removed anything from my main file that was possible to remove and it still throws the same error message even though the name Bíro isn't even in the main document. I'm really clueless as to what to try now..

tex file should be downloadable here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/831x3uukqkkcicd/Paper.zip?dl=0

Comment: Remove the `.aux` file and rerun LaTex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you abort the LaTeX run at the error (due to using a non ASCII character in a bibliographic cite key), the `.aux` file will not be flushed, because this happens later.

Make sure you don’t use any accented letter in your bibliographic cite keys, then remove the `.aux` file manually and run LaTeX (and possibly BibTeX, if you use it) again to get things back in sync.

Comment: Nice!  I ran into the issue highlighted above, fixed my cite keys and removed the `.bbl` but not the `.aux` and was still stuck; this answer got me sorted out.  Thanks.